# ASP.NET MVC 4 Controller Fails No type was found that matches the controller named 'account'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get this URL to work:

```
http://localhost:41359/account/login
```

Here is my MVC Controller I created:

```
namespace CTHRC.Roti.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ModelContext", "Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            return View();
        }
     }
}
```

and everytime I go to that URL I get this error message:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:41359/account/login'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'account'."}
```

I tried adding a MapRoute to it and still I get the same error:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Account",
                url: "account/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You trying to hit that with AJAX?

Comment: As an aside, you should put your more specific routes before your more general ones. As you have your routes defined, the `Account` route will never be reached as the `Default` routes satisfies the condition.

Comment: I am still getting the same error when I move Accounts mapping before Default....any other suggestion?

Comment: No I am just trying to goto that URL in my browser

Comment: do you have your controller in the default controllers folder? or you are writing it on a different project?

Comment: Yes...I have all my controllers with my other controllers

Answer (score -1):

When you add routes, it will always try to find something based on the order you add them. so if you place a "wildcard" first, it will never go to the next one.

Try this:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Account",
                url: "account/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
```